# Can a development server communicate with a Flask server running on the same host without a proxy?

Tags: flask, proxy, localhost

I have my Flask server which is listening on 127.0.0.1/localhost port 5000 by default.

I have a React app that I'm developing and testing on a dev server using `npm run dev` on the same machine. My assumption here is that since they are both on the same machine, my app should be able to fetch data using localhost:5000, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

After I configured the dev server with proxies to localhost:5000, it works.

Why can't they talk via localhost even if they are on the same machine?

FWIW, I am accessing the web app through Chrome and seeing connection refused issues.

Comment: Did you enabled CORS?

Comment: I've enabled CORS on my flask server with `socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")`

Comment: Maybe you should put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in order to facilitate.